# GetChanges REST call from java returning status 400

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, rest

I'm trying to use the `GetChanges` REST API call in SharePoint 2013 from a standalone Java app using Apache HttpClient. The JSON body in the POST request body looks like this:

```
{"Web":true,"query":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.ChangeQuery"}},"Update":true}
```

which matches the sample at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn499819%28v=office.15%29.aspx

I'm setting the `Accept and Content-type` headers to:

```
"application/json;odata=verbose"
```

and also setting the `X-RequestDigest` header to the `FormDigestValue` from the contextinfo request.

But I get back a 400 response with this message:

> "The parameter Web does not exist in method GetChanges."

If I omit the `Web` and `Update` properties from the request there is no error but I get an empty results array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON Body Should be

```
"{ 'query': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.ChangeQuery' }, 'Web': true, 'Update': true } }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue: The parameters such as Web and Update must be *inside* the query object, not outside.